# Can a type in C have more than one object representation?

Tags: c, data-representation, bit-representation

The C99 standard, section 6.2.6.1 8, states:

> When an operator is applied to ***a value that has more than one object
>   representation***, which object representation is used shall not affect
>   the value of the result (43). Where a value is stored in an object using a
>   ***type that has more than one object representation for that value***, it
>   is unspecified which representation is used, but a trap representation
>   shall not be generated.

I understood object to mean a location (bytes) in memory and value as the interpretation of those bytes based on the type used to access it. If so, then:

1. How can a value have more than one object representation?
2. How can a type have more than one object representation for a value?

The standard adds the below in the footnote:

[image]

Still, it's not clear to me. Can someone please simplify it for me and explain with examples?

Comment: For instance if sign/magnitude was used to encode numbers, there would be a two values representing `0`: positive zero and negative zero.

Comment: There’s a related article on floating-point numbers and their encoding (i.e. object representation) [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FLP37-C.+Do+not+use+object+representations+to+compare+floating-point+values). For example, the value `1.5` can have several representations in _n_-bit fixed or floating-point type. Regarding your addendum 43) I think that relates to interpreting bits, e.g. as signed/unsigned integers, or as floats, etc.

Comment: @Blaze: Yes, with sign-and-magnitude, are two ways of representing mathematical zero, but they are not the same value in the meaning of the C standard. Note that we can distinguish between them: If `x` is positive zero and `y` is negative zero, and they are 32 bits, then `x|1` is +1 and `y|1` is −1. As we see from the last sentence in the footnote, this “other operation” on `x` and `y` distinguishes between them, showing they do not have the same “value” as C defines the term, even though `x == y` evaluates to true. C defines “value” as the “precise meaning” (3.19), not the mathematical value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ah, so they need to have the same value even for bitwise operations. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An *object* is a region of storage (memory) that can contain values of a certain type [C18 3.15].

An *object representation* are the Bytes that make up the contents of an object [C18 6.2.6.1].

Not every possible combination of Bytes in an object representation also has to correspond to a value of the type (an object representation that doesn't is called a *trap representation* [C18 3.19.4]).

And not all the Bits in an object representation have to participate in representing a value. Consider the following type:

```c
struct A
{
    char c;
    int n;
};
```

Compilers are allowed to (and generally will) insert padding Bytes between the members `c` and `n` of this struct to ensure correct alignment of `n`. These padding Bytes are part of an object of type `struct A`. They are, thus, part of the object representation. But the values of these padding Bytes do not have any effect on the logical value of type `A` that is stored in the object.

Let's say we're on a target platform where Bytes consist of 8 Bits, an `int` consists of 4 Bytes in little endian order, and there are 3 padding Bytes between `c` and `n` to ensure that `n` starts at an offset that is a multiple of 4. The value `(struct A){42, 1}` may be stored in an object as

```
2A 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
```

But it may as well be stored in an object as

```
2A FF FF FF 01 00 00 00
```

or whatever else the padding Bytes may happen to be. Each of these sequences of Bytes is a valid object representation of *the same* logical value of type `struct A`.

This is also what the footnote is about. If you had two objects `x` and `y` that each contained a different object representation of the same value of type `struct A`, then `x == y` will evaluate to true while simply performing a `memcmp()` will not since `memcmp()` simply compares the bytes of the object representation without any consideration as to what the logical value stored in these objects actually is…

Comment: The C99 rationale mentions that the committee was told that there was a machine that used 2 16-bit shorts to make up a 32-bit int, with the sign bit of the lower short being ignored, and that was one reason to add padding bytes to the standard.

Comment: @ninjalj: That is not clear. First, with 2 16-bit shorts making up one 32-bit int, there are no spare bytes to be padding bytes, so what padding bytes are you referring to? Second, if one of the sign bits is ignored, you have only 31 bits for the `int`, not 32. Do you mean one sign bit is treated as a value bit, not ignored?

Comment: Padding doesn't have to come in units of Bytes though. The C Standard specifically has a concept of padding bits that are all the Bits of the object representation of an integer type that do not participate in the value representation of that integer type…I guess that's what ninjalj was referring to…

Comment: Consider also a struct that contains bit-fields. Unless all bit-field members perfectly fit into whatever storage units the compiler allocated for them, there will be individual Bits left over that are part of the object representation but not relevant to representing a value of the struct type…

Comment: @EricPostpischil: sorry, that should have been padding bit, lapsus calami. I'm just reporting what the Rationale says, it doesn't mention which machine it was, so I have not dug further.

Comment: @ninjalj where can I find the C99 rationale you referred to?

Comment: @user3124390: it's available from the Working Group page at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/

Answer (score 3):

> How can a value have more than one object representation?
>   How can a type have more than one object representation for a value?

Yes, by not having each bit pattern correspond to a different value.

Typically 1 bit pattern is preferred, [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form), and others rarely generated by normal means.

1. The [x86 extended precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) contains bit patterns that are the same value of other bit patterns - even with the same sign.  Research the "pseudo denormal" and "unnormal" bit patterns.

A side effect is that this 80-bit encoding does not realize 2<sup>80</sup> different values due to this redundancy.  (even after accounting for not-a-numbers)

2. Using [2 `double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) to encode a `long double` has a similar impact.

Oversimplified example of 2 `double` representing a `long double` value:

`1000001.0 + 0.0` (canonical form) same *value* as `1000000.0 + 1.0`

3. [Decimal floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) has this issue too.

> Because the significand is not normalized, most values with less than 16 significant digits have multiple possible representations; 1×102=0.1×103=0.01×104, etc.

---

As multiple bit patterns for the same value reduce the gamut of possible numbers, such encodings tend to fall out of favor compared to non-redundant ones.  An effect is that we do  not seem them as much these days.

A reason for their existence in the first place was to facilitate hardware realizations or simple easy to define (let's explicitly encode the most significant digit for our new FP format - using an implied one is so confusing).

---

@Eric brought up an interesting comment concerning *value* and *operator* that hinges on:

> Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation, which object representation is used shall not affect the value of the result. C17 § 6.2.6.2 8

Given `x = +0.0` and `y = -0.0`, which have the same *numeric value* of zero, would still qualify as having different values as the *operator* `/` distinguishes them as in `1.0/x != 1.0/y`.

Still the various FP examples above have many other cases where `x,y` have different bit pattern yet the same *value*.

Comment: The C standard’s meaning of “value” is not the numeric or mathematical value. The fact that two floating-point objects with different bits represent the same mathematical value does not mean they represent the same C value. If you can distinguish two objects of type `T` using operations on values of type `T`, then the objects do not represent the same value. For example, if `signbit(x) != signbit(y)`, `x` and `y` have different C values, even if they are +0 and −0. The C standard’s allowance of multiple representations for one value is for non-value bits, such as padding bits, to vary.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The usage of _value_ in 6.2.6.1 8 includes cases where `a == b` yet differ in bit pattern.  That is OP's question as to why and the examples of this answer example it.  The +0, -0 issue is not suggested by this answer so does not serve as a counter example.  "multiple representations for one value is for non-value bits, such as padding bits, to vary" is true and is another example, but does not negate the various FP ones.

Comment: Multiple patterns of value bits that represent the same value may fall into the C standard’s meaning for value, but only if there is no way to distinguish them at all using operations on values of the applicable type. That means no function to return the sign bit, no function to return the actual (versus normalized) exponent or significand, and so on. Is that what you are proposing? If so, I suggest clarifying that in the answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agree about the "no way to distinguish them using" an _operator_.  I do not find C support that extends that restriction to functions.  Perhaps you know of one? Answer amended.

Comment: The footnote says “operations”, not “operator”. However, that does not matter: If you can pass `x` and `y` to a function that distinguishes them, then there is a difference in the values of `x` and `y` because they are passed by value. If 30e0 and 3e1 were the same value as the C standard means it, and you passed bits encoding 30e0 to a function, the C implementation would be entitled to passed 3e1, since they are the same value. So being able to extract the exponents by passing `x` and `y` by value to a function reveals that their values are different.

Answer (score 2):

> explain with examples?

For example on a compiler that to represent `float` type uses [decimal floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point) according to IEEE 754-2008 standard, assuming that stars are properly aligned - `CHAR_BIT=8`, `sizeof(int)==4`, `float`s have width of 32-bits with no padding bits and the compiler uses little endian, the following code (tested with gcc9.2 with `-Dfloat=typeof(1.0df)`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
        float a, b;
        // simulate `a = 314` and `b = 314` with a compiler
        // that chose to use different object representation for the same value
        memcpy(&a, (int[1]){0x3280013a}, 4);
        memcpy(&b, (int[1]){0x32000c44}, 4);
        printf("a = %d, b = %d\n", (int)a, (int)b);
        printf("a %s b and memcpy(&a, &b) %s 0\n",
               a == b ? "==" : "!=",
               memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(a)) == 0? "==" : "!=");
}
```

should (could) output:

```
a = 314, b = 314
a == b and memcpy(&a, &b) != 0
```

Comment: I started writing an answer along these lines, but I do not think it is correct. What C means by “value” is not the numeric value. 3.19 defines “value” as “precise meaning of the contents of an object when interpreted as having a specific type”. If that “precise meaning” were solely the numeric value, then the last sentence in the footnote, “Furthermore, `x == y` does not imply that `x` and `y` have the same value; other operations on values of type `T` may distinguish between them.” could not be true. In order for +0 and −0 to have different values, their value must be more than the number 0.

Comment: For example, `signbit(+0.)` and `signbit(-0.)` return different things. So the “precise meaning” of `+0.` and `-0.` includes more than just the mathematical value 0. Also note that the specification of `==` does not say it produces true if the two objects have the same value. It says it produces true if the two objects are equal. So it is operating at a different layer of meaning than value. I think that leaves us with the meaning in Michael Kenzel’s answer—a value can have multiple object representations when the object contains more bits than are used for the value itself.

Comment: That includes 10-byte floating-point numbers that use 16 bytes for alignment benefits, unions where the current member does not fill the bytes, and structures with padding.

Comment: Oooch, I get it. I wanted to answer only the examples part leaving the harder "what exactly is a value" questions, but the examples are also wrong - they don't show it, they just compare different values for variables that compare equal. I am trying to prepare an example with `decimal32_t`, I think it could be better.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example of a value with more than one representation is an IEEE floating point zero. It has a "positive zero" and a "negative zero" representations.

*Note* An implementation that conforms to IEC 60559 must distinguish between positive and negative zeros, so in such an implementation they are different values rather than different representations of the same value. However an implementation doesn't need to conform to IEC 60559. Such implementations are allowed to e.g. always rerurn the same value for signbit of zero, even though the underlying hardware distinguishes +0 and -0.

On a sign-and-magnitude machine, integer zeros also have more than one representation.

On a segmented architecture like the 16-bit 8086, "long" pointers have more than one representation, for example 0x0000:0x0010 and 0x0001:0x0000 are two representations of the same pointer value.

Finally, in any data type with padding, padding bits do not influence the value. Examples include structs with padding holes.

Comment: See my note on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59138379/298225)—I do not think this is correct. The +0 and −0 are different values as defined by C, even though they compare equal. The “value” as defined by the C standard is the “precise meaning” of the object, which includes its behavior with the `signbit` function, not just its mathematical value.

Comment: As I understand the C standard’s meaning of “value,” zeros in sign-and-magnitude format are not an example of a value with more than one representation. From the last sentence in the footnote, we can see that, if an operation on the type `T` can distinguish two objects of type `T`, then they have different values. If `x` is positive zero and `y` is negative zero, then `x|1` is +1 but `y|1` is −1. So `x` and `y` do not have the same value in the meaning of the C standard, even though `x == y` evaluates to true.